# Не работает передача параметра из url в getter. Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex, vue-router

Всем привет! Не работает передача параметра из переменной в геттер шины vue js.

В store.js есть функция геттер

```
getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
  return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
}
```

в компоненте пытаюсь считать URL и передать параметр id аргументом.

```
{
  path: '/todos/:id',
  component: productPage,
  name: 'product',
  props: true
},
```

в компоненте происходит это так:

```
export default {
props: ['id'],
computed: {
  ad () {
    const id = this.id
    return this.$store.getters.getTodoById(id)
  }
},
```

}

если посмотреть содержимое this.id будет число, например 1, по попытка передать `this.id` или константу `id` не кончается успехом... если же просто передать число например 1 все работает. Пробовал и на прямую через `this.$router.currentRoute.params.id`, по разному, 0 результата.

Comment: Приведенный код кажется полностью правильным, нужно больше кода увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

Из данного кода могу сказать только, что у вас this.id, не проброшен правильно.

Попробуйте получить id через this.$route.params.paramName
В вашем случае this.$route.params.id